# Endian conversion in C signed

Tags: c, unix

I was trying to write signed integer value in a file in big endian.

I'm using this code :

```
int32_t swap_int32( int32_t val )
{
    val = ((val << 8) & 0xFF00FF00) | ((val >> 8) & 0xFF00FF ); 
    return (val << 16) | ((val >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
}
```

It works fine with negative value but I've some issues with positive value :

-5 gives me :

```
$> hexdump OUTPUT
ff ff ff fb
```

Which is correct

but 1337 gives me :

```
  $> hexdump OUTPUT
     00 00 05 39
```

Instead of (expected) 00 00 39 05.

Is there anyway to treat both cases and get correct result ?
Thanks you.

Comment: I have a feeling that -1337 won't work either.

Comment: It has nothing to do with positive and negative, but rather absolute values greater than 255.

Comment: 1337 is 0x539 so in big endian it's 00 00 05 39, not 00 00 39 05.

Comment: tutorial here: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/writing-endian-independent-code-in-c-r2091

Comment: don't do shifts with signed values unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Signed Integer Network and Host Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878781/signed-integer-network-and-host-conversion)

Answer (score 3):

Is there some problem with using [htonl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonla)?

```
   #include <arpa/inet.h>

   uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);
```

The values in the bytes should stay the same, so even though you want a signed value and htonl take an unsigned as long as you read it back into a signed type you shouldn't lose data. (As noted by mctylr, network order is big-endian.)

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int32_t pos = 1337;
  int32_t neg = -123;
  printf("host-endian:  %d => 0x%08x  %d => 0x%08x \n", 
         pos, pos, neg, neg);

  uint32_t big_endian_pos = htonl(pos);
  uint32_t big_endian_neg = htonl(neg);

  printf("Big-endian:   %d => 0x%08x %d => 0x%08x \n", 
         pos, big_endian_pos, neg, big_endian_neg);

}
```

And the output on my little-endian host:

```
[tmp]$ gcc endian.c  && ./a.out 
host-endian:  1337 => 0x00000539  -123 => 0xffffff85 
Big-endian:   1337 => 0x39050000  -123 => 0x85ffffff
```

Comment: To clarify, *network byte order* is **big** endian. So on either an little endian or big endian host (system), the network long (unsigned 32-bit integer) is written in big endian byte ordering.

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, you should cast to "unsigned" inside your function.

As an alternative, you can always use the network macros "htons()" (16-bit) and "htonl()" (32-bit) to convert host to network (big-endian) byte order.

Comment: Good point. `x >> y` might be an arithmetic shift when `x` is signed, depending on the compiler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/shift-operator-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Network byte order is big endian.

POSOX UNIX has htonl(), htons() and friends to do just what you require. They guarantee big endian from any system.

Answer (score 0):

On *BSD and Linux systems you can use [`byteorder(9)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=byteorder&sektion=9) functions including `bswap_32()` when used on a little [endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) host.

```
#include <sys/endian.h>  /* other platforms may need: sys/param.h endian.h or byteswap.h */
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t in, out;

out = bswap_32(in);
```

On little endian MS Windows systems, [`_byteswap_ulong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3140177%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is included in `stdlib.h`, even though it is not standard.

Otherwise various [bit twiddling examples](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/endian/) can be easily found across the Internet.

And StackOverflow

- convert big endian to little endian in C {without using provided func} [2182002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-in-c-without-using-provided-func)
- How do I convert between big-endian and little-endian values in C++? [105252](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c)
- Fast little-endian to big-endian conversion in ASM [1358747](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358747/fast-little-endian-to-big-endian-conversion-in-asm) - 2 out of 3 answers are not C# oriented